# xs:choice embedded in xs:sequence prevents the use of a union

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, gsoap, xsd-validation

I have the following xsd

```
<xsd:complexType name="myID">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="testID" type="priv:testID"/>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="newID" type="priv:newID"/>
            <xsd:element name="testID" type="priv:testID" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Everything is under `priv` namespace. The problem is that it looks like that `myID` is a union. It might be a `testID` or a sequence with `newID` and `testID`. When I compile it with `wsdl2h` from `gsoap` I am taking the message:

> Note: `<xs:choice>` with embedded
>   `<xs:sequence>` or `<xs:group>`
>   prevents the use of a union

Is the above XSD correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the XML type `myID` can be declared as you described. The conflict exist probably in connection with your definition of the types `priv:testID` and `priv:testID` which definition you not included. For example the schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/xml/xsd/1.0/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:priv="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/xml/xsd/1.0/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
    <xsd:simpleType name="testID">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="newID">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="myID">
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="testID" type="priv:testID"/>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="newID" type="priv:newID"/>
                <xsd:element name="testID" type="priv:testID" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="root" type="priv:myID"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

will be correct. So if an error exist, it is not in the part which you posted.

Comment: Your XSD is more complete than mine. The question is "is it legal to nest a sequence in the xsd:choice"?